# Whether to use "the" before abbreviations such as HTTP

Tags: articles, definite-articles, abbreviations

> ... This setting determines whether HTTP and FTP URIs should be turned into relative ones if a file is stored using the HTTP or the FTP.

*HTTP* stands for *hypertext transfer **protocol***, and *FTP* stands for *file transfer **protocol***.

Whether we should use the definite article before *HTTP* and *FTP* in this sentence? Or maybe *HTTP* and *FTP*, when they are used as abbreviations, are treated more like proper names, such as *NATO*, without the article?

> - UNESCO designates World Heritage Sites.
> - Finland is not a member of NATO.

**Edit:** I mean the "bold" the:

> ... This setting determines whether HTTP and FTP URIs should be turned into relative ones if a file is stored using **the** HTTP or **the** FTP.

Comment: It could be either way. Like whether (the) chairs should be put under (the) tables.

Comment: “… using using those protocols.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URIs are properties of the file, so the shortest approach is to use *its* instead of *the* or nothing. It would be clearer though to say "This setting determines whether the HTTP and FTP URIs of a file should be turned into relative ones if the file is stored using HTTP or FTP.

Comment: So there is no need to use "the" in the end of the sentence?

Comment: No, you don't need "the" for HTTP, nor for FTP. The "the" I put in refers to URIs. It is like "the" refers to apples in "the red and green apples".

Comment: But why? What is the logic behind not using "the" before HTTP/FTP when they are used on their own and not as a part of compound nouns? Maybe there is no logic at all? I'm from Russia, therefore my question may sound kind of naive for native speakers.

Comment: HTTP is a defined standard; it is not just any protocol for transferring hypertext. This may be why it is treated as a proper noun like the name of a person or a company. Proper nouns (names) don't normally have "a" or "the" used with them. In the same way we don't talk about the England or the IBM.